# Metaprogramming sinatra get

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, sinatra

I have a list of words in a list, and I want to handle get requests to any of them (and respond the same way).

```
@words = ["foo","bar"....etc]
```

One of the ways I thought I could do this is to loop through the list and have a get directive generated for each word when sinatra is launched.

```
@words.each do |word|
    get word do
       # what to do
    end
end
```

that doesn't work, but something in that fashion, maybe.

Another way of doing it might be responding to `get %r{/(.+)}` and then doing some processing inside there to see if it matches anything in the list and respond accordingly, but I'm interested nonetheless to see if there's a way I can do it as described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. What you wrote does work, with a very minor change. For example:

   ```
   require 'sinatra'
   %w[foo bar].each do |word|
     get "/#{word}" do
       "You said #{word}!"
     end
   end
   ```

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost:4567/bar
   You said bar!
   ```
2. Instead of a catch-all regex route, you can craft a custom regexp dynamically to match only the words you want to match:

   ```
   require 'sinatra'
   words = %w[foo bar]
   route_re = %r{^/(#{words.join '|'})$}i # case-insensitive
   p route_re
   #=> /^\/(foo|bar)$/i

   get route_re do |name|
     "You said #{name}!"
   end
   ```

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost:4567/FoO
   You said FoO!

   $ curl -I http://localhost:4567/jim
   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
   X-Cascade: pass
   Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
   Content-Length: 413
   Connection: keep-alive
   Server: thin 1.2.7 codename No Hup
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you need, this might be enough:

```
get '/:word' do
  # check if params[:word] is in your list
  # and respond accordingly
  if @words.include?(params[:word])
      "yeeah"
  else
      pass
  end
end
```

But keep in mind that this route matches everything.

Comment: Well you can add pass in the else clause